# Flex HTTPService contentType = "application/json" with parameters

Tags: apache-flex, httpservice

I make a Flex HTTPService:

```
<s:HTTPService id="svn" url="{Globals.URLINDEX}" result="doLoginCheck(event);"  
           resultFormat="text" fault="faultHandler(event)"  method="POST"  />
```

and have a PHP file *a.php*:

```
<?php
echo "{ ";
echo  '"act" :' . '"'. $_REQUEST['act'] .'"    ' ;
echo "}";
?>
```

problem is here.

If I send it like this, without *contentType*:

```
var params = {} ;
params.act ="act";
//svn.contentType = "application/json";   
svn.headers = {Accept : "application/json"}; 
svn.send(params);
```

result is OK.

```
{ "act": "act" ...}
```

But I send it like this, with *contentType*:

```
svn.contentType = "application/json";   
svn.headers = {Accept : "application/json"};
```

result have problem

```
{"act" ,"" ...    }
```

(blank  .  can't get parameter)

How to solve this?